# Битрикс календарь

Tags: битрикс, дата, calendar, limit

```
<label class="control-label" >Дата рождения<span class="asterisk">*</span>:</label>
<input type="text" value="01.01.1933" name="PERSONAL_BIRTHDAY" class="input_middle_privat" id="birthday_input">
```

Мне нужно , чтобы пользователь мог вводить данные(используя календарь bitrix) в определенном диапазоне, это текущая дата - 90лет , до текущей даты.

```
<input type="text" value="01.01.1933" name="PERSONAL_BIRTHDAY" class="input_middle_privat" onclick="BX.calendar({
    node: this,
    field: this,
    bTime: false,
    min: new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 90, new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()), // Текущая дата минус 90 лет
    max: new Date() // Текущая дата
});">
```

пробовал такой вариант , не получилось